# MySQL latin1 to UTF-8 using Java & Hibernate & JPA

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I have a database that is in charset=latin1 and collation latin1_swedish_ci. The user has entered UTF-8 characters in this connection ( Greek characters ) and in PHP he can read everything just fine.

But when I try to read the database using JAVA + JPA + Hibernate ( all Latest versions ) the characters are totally broken.

Note that I have already tried my jdbc string with:

```
...?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=latin1&amp;connectionCollation=latin1_swedish_ci
...?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
...?characterSetResults=ISO8859_1
...and combinations of those
```

but still I can't read the characters.

The best I have managed is to use:

```
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes(windows-1252); 
String fixed = new String(ptext, UTF_8);
```

with:

```
?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
```

But still there are many characters that in eclipse's output are "?" and in log4j output everything is broken.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `latin1` does not support Greek characters, so whatever the database stores now is totally broken. If the characters appear correctly when the PHP application reads the database, it must be a case of two wrongs making a right.

Comment: I know. Exactly what you say. I believe it works by total Luck :) . I found a workaround. I select the column as:

"CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(column_name USING latin1) USING binary) using utf8)"

But still I need to make it work in JPA + Hibernate

Comment: Is converting the tables to utf8 an option?

Comment: No. The project is already quite big and it's administrators are not willing to risk such a big change right now.

Comment: In that case you won't be able to store Greek text reliably. You can program a kludge that massages the text after getting it from the database so that most of the time things seem to work, but the system is inherently broken

Comment: Which characters in particular don't make it through the `new String(text.getBytes("CP1252"), "UTF-8")` kludge? I would expect most to be OK.

Comment: Yes with the solution you propose Most characters are ok. But characters like "ρ" or "Ν" (Greek N ) and characters with accents are broken and displayed as questionmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT( column_name USING latin1) USING binary) using utf8) FROM...
```

But it ties you down to Native SQL. You cannot use JPA Queries. There is no other way. Only MySQL knows how to convert what it converted when the data was entered in the database.

Comment: Yes, there is another way: recover the data from the result set as bytes using the [getBytes method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBytes%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's version of latin1 is an extended version of CP1252: [it uses the 5 bytes that CP1252 leaves undefined](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-we-sets.html). Unfortunately the current Connector/J has a ["bug"](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64071) in that it uses the original CP1252 rather than MySQL's own version. Therefore it's impossible to recover strings whose encoding uses one of these 5 bytes. Patching the Connector/J source to fix the bug could solve the problem, but ideally you should migrate the tables to UTF-8.

A workaround is using the the JDBC `getBytes` method instead of `getString` to get data from the result set, this way going around the broken encoding handling in the client library:

```
String recovered = new String(resultSet.getBytes(1), "UTF-8");
```

I'm not sure if this can help you because with JPA and Hibernate you are quite removed from the JDBC API.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried your solution and it works but not for all characters.

Comment: So basically your options are A) fix the database B) fix the bug in MySQL connector/j or find a workaround with a combination of the different options C) patch the charset in the JDK to make cp1252 match MySQL's latin1